# Why am I getting errors saying "Unused Parameter n"?

Tags: c, cs50, linear-search

I have been trying to solve this cs50 pset3. I wrote this linear search algorithm and when I try to run it I get error saying "Unused parameter n", "Unused parameter values". Can anyone please tell me why am I getting this error. I tried re-arranging my code several times.
Thank you,

```
bool linear_search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    if (n < 1)  //if n is negative it has to return false.
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] == value)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
    return false;    //it returns false if the value is not in values.
}
```

Comment: `return result` is not in the `if` statement, so it will be executed the first time through the loop, regardless of whether the value is found.

Comment: See [ask] and provide **all** required information, including a [mcve]. This is hardly an error message, but a warning.

Comment: Unless something is very wrong indeed about your environment, the code you've presented is not the code to which the diagnostics pertain.  Maybe they pertain to a different function in the same file, or to a function in some other file.  Or there's an outside possibility that something preceding this function in the same translation unit is broken, changing the interpretation of what follows.

Comment: That wouldn't be an error, but a warning at compile time. The code you posted doesn't have such a problem. Could you post a full example and include how you're compiling the code and exactly what the error message is? Also your comment on `if (n < 1)  //if n is negative it has to return false` is wrong (`n < 1` is not always negative) and that check is unnecessary, the `for` loop will simply not run if `n < 1`.

Comment: Unused parameters meaning that you doesn't used function arguments in the function body, but in your code there isn't any unused parameter, maybe there is unused parameter in rest of the code.

Comment: @Schwern Some conventions might consider `0` as negative.. But I guess not in this case.

Comment: Such warnings are generated by specific compilers - "unused parameters" are not an error. What compiler and what flags do you use?

Comment: @EugeneSh. which conventions? Are you referring to the idea that there may be perverse variable types which can be `+0` or `-0`? As if!

Comment: @WeatherVane, you're quite right that one is unlikely to encounter implementations of *integer* types supporting negative zeroes, even though C permits them, but of course almost everyone has *floating-point* negative zeroes, because they are part of IEEE-754.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is what I was alluding to. The concept of `0` was a great advance in mathematics but I do struggle to understand why in computer representations `0` can be a plural **nothing**.

Comment: @WeatherVane in sign-magnitude representation, `0` has no sign bit set and negative-zero does have it set.

Comment: @WeatherVane, as a practical matter, in the FP case, there are numerical algorithms that are much more stable / better-behaved with signed zeroes than without.  Conceptually, one can interpret (either) signed zero as a number so small in magnitude as to not have a representation distinguishable from zero's, despite possibly being nonzero.  Signed zero makes more sense in that context.

Comment: @M.M are there different properties of `+0` and `-0`? For example, would the square root of `-0` generate an error?

Comment: @JohnBollinger so is there a FP representation that says the number ***is*** `0` and not somewhere close to `0`? If `-0` implies that the negative number is close to `0`, how can `+0` distinguish actual `0` from almost `0`?

Comment: @WeatherVane `sqrt` is a floating point function. The C standard allows `sqrt(-0.0)` to be either `-0.0` or `+0.0`.

Comment: @M.M that's very interesting. I have just written a small test program which establishes that the square root of `-0.0` is `-0.0`. Bonkers! When I square that square root of `-0.0` it give `0.0` and not the original `-0.0`.

Comment: For those asking what it says in the error. I get three errors and they are as follows.

Comment: For those asking what it says in the error. I get three errors and they are as follows.
    
helpers.c:40:15: error: unused parameter 'values' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
void sort(int values[], int n)
              ^
helpers.c:40:29: error: unused parameter 'n' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
void sort(int values[], int n)

Comment: `n < 1` is not a test for 'if n is negative'.

Comment: None of the errors you have just posted refers to anything in the code you posted. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated at the comments, the n that causes error is a parameter of another function

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
```

This is another function you have to implement in that HW. You can temporarily use n like n = n+1; in that function until you implement it.

The reason you get this as an error instead of warning is -Werror flag you using with clang (see the Makefile). This tells clang to treat warnings as errors so you will be forced to correct them before you can execute the program and probably submit the homework.

Comment: Thank you.. I figured it out.